# APP_INITIALIZER function from library

Tags: angular, function, configuration

recently I found myself writing, for every Angular App I'm making, the same init_app method inside an AppLoadingModule.
So I decided to write a lib with all common stuff between my projects. I want to move this init_app function inside the lib.

May I explain better:
I have a service in my lib that loads a configuration file from the assets folder.
At the moment in my app-loading.module.ts for my angular application I have the following code:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: init_app, multi: true, deps: [
      ConfigurationService,
      HttpClient
    ]}
  ]
})
export class AppLoadingModule {}

export function init_app(
  configurationService: ConfigurationService,
  http: HttpClient
): () => Promise<any> {
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const env = environment.production ? 'production' : 'development';
      console.log(`init_app:: ${env}`);
      Promise.all([
        configurationService.loadConfiguration(http, env)
      ])
      .then(() => {
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Error fetching configuration: ${err}`);
        // Try continue
        resolve();
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Is there a way to move or call this function from the lib? I was trying to move the entire app-loading.module.ts inside the core library, but I can't reference environment.ts.

Comment: Hi You can define a function on window object and pass the require parameter from AppLoading module here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your answer. Could you please provide an example?